# sed comand is not replacing value after first match

Tags: sed, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to add a line in a file using sed after first match. I looked my threads online, addressing the same issue and tried below versions of the command:

1. `sudo sed -e '/cfg_file/cfg_file='$NEW_FILE -e '/cfg_file/cfg_file=/q' MAIN_CONF_FILE`
2. `sudo sed -i '0,/cfg_file/ a\cfg_file='$NEW_FILE $MAIN_CONF_FILE`
3. `sudo sed -i '1s/cfg_file/cfg_file='$NEW_FILE $MAIN_CONF_FILE`
4. `sudo sed -i '1/cfg_file/s/cfg_file='$NEW_FILE $MAIN_CONF_FILE`

Unfortunately, nothing worked for me. Either they show error, in case of point 3, or show similar behavior of adding lines after each match.

**SAMPLE FILE**

> ```
> cfg_file=some_line1
> cfg_file=some_line2
> ```

Now I want to add a line after first match of cg_file, like below.

**EXPECTED RESULT**

> ```
> cfg_file=some_line1
> cfg_file=my_added_line_after_first_match_only.
> cfg_file=some_line2
> ```

Help me in adding line after first match and correcting my command.

Comment: Edit your question to remove `replace` or `add` from the statement `I am trying to replace add a line` and add a [mcve].

Comment: Also, please add a sample input and expected output. Otherwise, it is hard to tell what changes need to be made to your command.

Comment: You want to add a line after the first line that matches your pattern and **only** after the first line that matches?

Comment: Don't experiment with `sudo` and the `-i` option.  Experiment on a copy of the file, saving the result to a temporary.  Only when you know it will work should you risk using `sudo` and `-i`.

Comment: But what should i try @jonathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're on Ubuntu, you are using GNU `sed`.  GNU `sed` has some weird features and some useful ones; you should ignore the weird ones and use the useful ones.

In context, the useful one is ranges starting at line 0.  Weird ones are the way it messes with `a`, `i` and `c` commands.

```
MAIN_CONF_FILE=/tmp/copy.of.main.config.file
NEWFILE="my_added_line_after_first_match_only."

sed -e '0,/^cfg_file=/ { /^cfg_file/ a\' \
    -e "cfg_file=$NEWFILE" \
    -e '}' \
    "$MAIN_CONF_FILE"
```

In classic `sed`, the `a` command is followed by backslash-newline, and each subsequent line of the script is appended up to and including the first line without a backslash at the end (and the backslash is removed).  Each `-e` argument functions as a line in the script.  Distinguish between the shell lines escaped with backslash at the end and the `sed` script lines with backslash at the end.

#### Example at work

```
$ cat /tmp/copy.of.main.config.file | so
cfg_file=some_line1
cfg_file=some_line2
$ cat script.sh
MAIN_CONF_FILE=/tmp/copy.of.main.config.file
NEWFILE="my_added_line_after_first_match_only."

SED=/opt/gnu/bin/sed

${SED} \
    -e '0,/^cfg_file=/ { /^cfg_file/ a\' \
    -e "cfg_file=$NEWFILE" \
    -e '}' \
    "$MAIN_CONF_FILE"
$ bash script.sh
cfg_file=some_line1
cfg_file=my_added_line_after_first_match_only.
cfg_file=some_line2
$
```

This is based on your attempt 2, but avoids some of the weird stuff.

#### Basic sanity

As I [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631737/sed-comand-is-not-replacing-value-after-first-match#comment60870832_36631737), it is not sensible to experiment with `sudo` and the `-i` option to `sed`.  You don't use those until you know that the script will do the job correctly.  It is dangerous to do anything as `root` via `sudo`.  It is doubly dangerous when you don't know whether what you're trying to use will work.  Don't risk wrecking your system.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Jonathan I will consider this

Comment: got this error,  line 25: /opt/gnu/bin/sed: No such file or directory

Comment: That's where I keep my copy of GNU `sed`; just change the assignment to `SED=sed` and you should be OK.

Comment: I tried this but still no success, ;( `sed -e '0,/^cfg_file=/ { /^cfg_file/ a\' \
    -e "cfg_file=$NEW_FILE" \
    -e '}' \
    "$MAIN_CONF_FILE"`

Comment: Sorry, but bedtime arrives.  If you take the file I showed, and you take the shell script shown and you fix the location of `sed`, and you run it, are you getting a different result from what I show?   If so, you'd better explain what you are getting.  If your problem is adapting it to your more realistic example, then maybe you need to show the more realistic example.

Comment: The problem is that the command made no changing in my MAIN_CONF_FILE.

Comment: The command I wrote doesn't modify any file. I don't write scripts that do that. It writes to standard output so you can see what it does. When you're satisfied that it works correctly by inspecting what it produces, and only then, do you think about running it with the prions that risk damaging your file.

Comment: your command is just making changes in the terminal but not actually appending the line in the file.

Comment: Yes. If course. It is not hard for you to add the `-i` option when you are satisfied it works.  Until then, I leave out the `-i` (and the `sudo`) so that you don't get hurt. You are allowed to think about what you are being told and how to use it.  And No, I have no plans to edit my answer for you to do every last jot and tittle of what you might need.  I try to avoid damage to your systems; it is up to you to do that!

Comment: I did it :) thankx. And thanks for your guidance and tips these are very helpful. :)